# detect all installed apps from Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, url-scheme

I'm trying to detect all installed apps on an iPhone from Safari.I have a list of 3000 URls scheme.From a WebView and using javascript, I want to loop this list and save the excitant apps (URls scheme that have a response) .Is that possible?

Comment: No, since the for each App URI scheme you are going to try the app will be launched.

Comment: what if the webView just check if it can open that specific URL scheme without opening it.I dont know if this has a meaning on JS.on iOS I use canOpenURL.

Comment: There is not `canOpenURL:` equivalent in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply not possible, as @rckoenes said, it would launch each app you call - therefore halting your browser instance - and looping through that many URIs even if it did return a value rather than launching the app would probably make you no friends. there are ways and means of detecting if YOUR app or AN app is present and launching it via smart meta banners or look at this project: https://github.com/hampusohlsson/browser-deeplink